# application working with smart card readers vs RDP and switching users

Tags: windows, smartcard, rdp

one windows application works with smart card readers. It has cycle like that:

```
do{
lErr = SCardListReaders( hContext, ... );
if ( lErr != SCARD_S_SUCCESS )
    return 1;
//Show readers
}while(!stop)
```

i.e. it gets current list of readers, than shows it.
The problem is that this does not work correct with `RDP` connection. Let's suppose we have computer A (COMP_A) with smart card reader A (READER_A), computer B (COMP_B) with reader B (READER_B). The application is launched on COMP_A and shows READER_A in the list of readers. Then we connect from COMP_B to COMP_A via `RDP.` Correct result of this must be that there is READER_B in the list. But the application "crashes" because `SCardListReaders` returns `SCARD_E_SERVICE_STOPPED.`
Some goggling gave answer that we need to re-establish context. So new version of cycle:

```
do{
lErr = SCardListReaders( hContext, ... );
if ( lErr == SCARD_E_SERVICE_STOPPED )
{
    SCardReleaseContext( hContext );
    //Sleep(10000)
    SCardEstablishContext( ..., &hContext );
    lErr = SCardListReaders( hContext, ... );
}
if ( lErr != SCARD_S_SUCCESS )
    return 1;
//Show readers
}while(!stop)
```

It does not work, `SCardListReaders` returns READER_A in the list. I suppose because new `SCardEstablishContext` ends before RDP connection is finally set. At least if Sleep is uncommented it works correct.
The similar situation with user switching, i.e. `SCardListReaders` returns `SCARD_E_SERVICE_STOPPED` when user chooses "switch user".

The question is how to make correct code? How to determine that this is RDP connection or user switching? How to re-establish `scard context?`

Actually i made some changes which use `WTSQuerySessionInformation` function with `WTSClientProtocolType` parameter. I wait when `WTSClientProtocolType = 2` and then call `SCardEstablishContext`. But i am not sure this is correct and also it is not correct for switch user.

Comment: Please do provide full source, parameters do matter sometimes (like system or user context)

Comment: the test visual studio c++ 2008 project is here [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=5B3A90B0023284BF!107&authkey=!AMGmXhFsj9tMtRw). Click "SCardEstablishContext", "Run Thread". This will start the thread which shows list of readers. Check "sleep" checkbox before "Run Thread" to enable Sleep(10000) before re-establish context.